# Call Prototype Object Method in JQuery Event Handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I have an object called `Breadcrumb`, which has a function `expandEllipses`. The following works fine:

```
mbc = jQuery('#breadcrumb').breadcrumb({
    items : initItems
});

jQuery("body").on("click", ".breadcrumb .breadcrumbEllipses",  function(e) {
    mbc.expandEllipses();
});
```

However, I was wondering how to do this in a jQuery event handler where I don't have the object right there with me:

```
jQuery("body").on("click", ".breadcrumb .breadcrumbEllipses",  function(e) {
    parObj = <parent of the .breadcrumbEllipses instance that triggered this event> 
    protoObj = <Prototype object from parentObj>
    protoObj.expandEllipses();
});
```

---

This is what ended up working from [Barmar's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) answer:

```
jQuery.fn.breadcrumb = function(options) {
    var bc = new Breadcrumb(this, options);
    this.data('breadcrumb', bc);
    return bc;
}; 

jQuery("body").on("click", ".breadcrumb .breadcrumbEllipses",  function(e) {
    bcObj = jQuery(this).closest(".breadcrumb").data("breadcrumb");
    bcObj.expandEllipses();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `breadcrumb` initializer, save the `Breadcrumb` object in the element using `.data()`

```
this.data('breadcrumb', self);
```

Then you can retrieve it later:

```
jQuery("body").on("click", ".breadcrumb .breadcrumbEllipses",  function(e) {
    parObj = $(this).closest(".breadcrumb");
    protoObj = parObj.data("breadcrumb");
    protoObj.expandEllipses();
});
```

Comment: This looks very promising! However, I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: this.data is not a function` from `var Breadcrumb = function(element, options) {... this.data('breadcrumb', self); };`

Comment: My code was intended to be in `jQuery.fn.breadcrumb`. When a plugin function is called, `this` is the jQuery object it was called on.

Comment: And replace `self` with whatever variable you're using internally to hold the `Breadcrumb` object.

Comment: Ah ok - I put `this.data('breadcrumb', self);` in `jQuery.fn.breadcrumb` and data exists now. However, if I'm understanding the rest correctly, then my problem now is that I won't have access to the `Breadcrumb` object in our js file. We're building a "library" sort of, so they create the breadcrumb object, which displays a breadcrumb with ellipses for long paths. When you click the ellipses, it should expand automatically without further code from the developer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. From what you posted, I thought that `jQuery.fn.breadcrumb` creates the `Breadcrumb` object and returns it. So it should be able to put it into the data field before returning it. If the user can also create `Breadcrumb` objects independently, you need to provide a method for them to pass that into the plugin, perhaps as another option: `.breadcrumb({ breadcrumb: mbc })`

Comment: Oh I misunderstood what you wrote sorry. That seems like it's working. Thanks!